# Cache operations with SD/MMC driver in linux

Tags: caching, memory, linux-device-driver, sd-card

What is the functionality of `mmc_flush_cache` & `mmc_cache_ctrl` with MMC driver in linux.

I have found very little information on these, that mmc_flush_cache will flush the cache contents to the non volatile memory. But which cache memory they are referring to, whether MMC has it's own cache memory as like UFS device?

I need to copy the contents of cache to the MMC memory and from MMC memory to the cache. How I can achieve this in linux with the MMC driver.

Please suggest me the functions or API's using which I can do cache related operations in MMC driver.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The cache referred to is indeed the on-board cache on the MMC device. the function **`mmc_flush_cache()`** is mapped to the **[`EXT_CSD_FLUSH_CACHE`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mmc/mmc.h#L275)** MMC command.

Note that every MMC device does not have on-board cache and this command is not supported/implemented on devices that do not possess a cache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

So, it means that MMC will be having it's own cache. And for transfering data from cache to the NV memory I can make use of the mmc_flush_cache API? And is there any funtion for transfering data from NV memory to cache means pre-fetch?

Is there any tool for cache profiling after implementing?

Comment: In addition to the ones mentioned in your question, i do not know any functions to configure/control the mmc device cache explicitly.